# Метод slice() не работает для массива

Tags: javascript, slice

```
    const changeFilters = (obj) => {
        console.log(Object.values(obj), Object.keys(obj));
        console.log(obj);
        const values = Object.keys(obj).sliсe(1, 3);
        console.log(values);
    }
```

почему выходит такая ошибка, если применяю метод slice() к массиву?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что надо писать английскими буквами, а не русскими: `slice`, а не `sliсe`.